# How to read an url which contain JSON in a text file on the visual studio ,and after load the JSON write on another txt file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, es6-promise

Hi This is my very first time trying node.js so I have no idea what I am doing wrong .In addition, since we might want to generalize this process, I’ll need to insert the existing “Promises” code that handles the JSON retrieval, into a function expression called “getJSON” which takes a single parameter (the url).
Because we want the entire process to happen at startup, I should code “getJSON” as an IIFE with the url retrieved from urls.txt as the single IIFE parameter.Finally, in my resolve function located in the promises consuming section, I have to save the returned JSON string to a file called JSON.txt and return a message to the browser that says “JSON data saved to file” and echo the same message to the console. Every time I run I get an error on line 72 or (startURL). I`d appreciated any help , please

```
let fs = require('fs');

let readME = "JSON data saved to file";

let url = "./urls.txt"
fs.readFile('urls.txt', { encoding: 'utf8' }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error:Could not open the file for reading\n");
    }
    else {
        //fs.writeFile('json.txt', data);
        //console.log(readME);
        getJSON(url);
        document.write(readME);
    }
});

let http = require('http');

let express = require("express");
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
let app = express();

let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('/', express.static('pages'));

let getJSON = (function (url) {    
    // Here we create a promise , that could occur in the future
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        let req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.open('GET', 'http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2017/month_07/day_08/master_scoreboard.json');

        req.onload = function () {

            if (req.status === 200) {
                resolve(req.responseText);
                url(response);

                //resolve(JSON.parse(req.response));
            }
            else {
                reject(req.statusText);
            }
        };

        req.onerror = function () {
            reject("network error");
        };

        req.send();
    });

    getJSON(url).then(
        function (response) {
            req.send(response);

            fs.writeFile('json.txt', JSON.stringify(response));
            //let obj = JSON.parse(response);
            //let fs = require('fs');
            //fs.writeFile('json.txt', obj);

            document.write("JSON data saved to file");
        },
        function (error) {
            console.error("Request failed: ", error);
        }
    );
})(startURL);

let server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, function () {

    console.log("JSON data saved to file");
});

//app.listen(port, function () {
//    console.log('JSON data saved to file');
//});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you are doing there, to be honest. Using express and http.
I'd recommend using axios for a GET-request in node.

With only one url in 'urls.txt' a simple example using axios that could maybe solve your problem would be:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const axios = require("axios");

const urls = "./urls.txt";

fs.readFile(urls, "utf8", (err, data) => {
  axios.get(data).then(res => {
    fs.writeFile("json.txt", JSON.stringify(res.data), err => {
      if (!err) console.log("Written to file.");
    });
  });
});
```

Edit: Seems you want this to be triggered by a HTTP Get-Request

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
const urls = "./urls.txt";

app.get("/", (req, resp) => {
  fs.readFile(urls, "utf8", (err, data) => {
    axios.get(data).then(res => {
      fs.writeFile("json.txt", JSON.stringify(res.data), err => {
        if (!err) resp.send("Written to file.");
      });
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening for requests");
});
```

Comment: @user:5663507 Yes , I want this to be triggered by a HTTP Get-Request however I must use a IIFE promise. I tried the code above but I got an error on event.js that came up with throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event, any hint what could be ?